# device function pointer as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, nvrtc

I have a template struct for some reasons (beyond the scope of this question) :

```
template<typename T, __device__ retV (*funcptr)(T)>
struct func 
{
    __device__ inline retV invoke(T i) { funcptr(i); }
};
```

which can be used this way:

```
__device__ double increment(double x) {
    return x + 1.0;
}

__constant__ func<double, double, &increment> myfunc;

__device__ double apply(double x) 
{
    return myfunc.invoke(x);
}
```

This works well with nvcc (cuda 10.0), but fails with nvrtc (JIT compilation) with the following error:

> error: attributes may not appear here

How should I modify this code to make it work with nvrtc?
Or should I add flags in my command-line?

Comment: why the downvote please? Questions seems legit

Comment: Which CUDA toolkit and host compiler are you using?

Comment: Cuda 10.0 on windows. Visual 2017 latest. Same on Ubuntu 18.04. Likely gcc 5.4

Comment: I'm really surprised it compiles. Memory space attributes should never be applied to class data. The only time it is valid is for member functions. nvrtc is clang based, as far as I can tell, which might explain the difference, but I'll wager nvrtc is correct in this case

Answer (score 1):

Well, answer is quite easy :

`__device__` attribute is misplaced (as indicated by the compiler). The `func`struct should look like:

```
template<typename T, retV (* __device__  funcptr)(T)>
struct func 
{
    __device__ inline retV invoke(T i) { funcptr(i); }
};
```

But I don't know why nvcc and nvrtc have different expectations on this.

EDIT :
Nvrtc 11 and above does not support this syntax anymore. Probably because nvrtc is clang based